# Side By Side Panes

Tags: css, html

I'm building a HTML template for my site and would like to have a main content pane on the left and a navigation pane on the right (similar to Twitter).

I'm assuming DIVs are not the preferred approach since they are by defaulted listed top-to-bottom.  I've played around with float:left and float:right but those cause the parent div to not expand appropriately vertically.

I've seen references to using tables (seems like a step backwards) and SPANs (which I haven't been able to use to produce the right effect).

What is the best practice for accomplishing side-by-side panes in HTML?

Any advice or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Google "two column css", tons of examples...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm assuming DIVs are not the preferred approach since they are by defaulted listed top-to-bottom.

Why would you assume that when the example you gave, Twitter, uses them?

The parent `div` can be made to expand to the height of the larger of the two columns by putting a div below the two columns within the container div with `clear: both` as its CSS.

Answer (score 0):

DIVs with float is probably your best bet.  What is your problem with the height?  Have you tried doing `height: auto` for the div?